# VS 2017 - The Web Application Project [MyProject] is configured to use IIS. You do not have permission to access the IIS configuration FILE

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2017

My web application was working fine for months till today, don't know what has changed suddenly the project in my solution file says that it is "unavailable" when I open the solution. When I right-click on the web project and reload the project, I get the following error:.

> The Web Application Project myproject.myapp.mywebproject is configured
> to use IIS. You do not have permission to access the IIS configuration
> file. Opening and creating web sites on IIS requires running visual
> studio under Administrator account.

Note - All these months i was running visual studio normally(not under administrator account) and the application was working fine.

By seeing the above error i tried running my visual studio under administrator account and the project got loaded but the Source Control File Status beside all the files disappeared, i no longer see any blue lock icon beside any of the files and even when i edit any file also there is no status beside the file in my project and also when i right click on any of the file i don't see the view history option.

My project which was running successfully till now not loading the project. any suggestions on this ?

Comment: "Note - All these months i was running visual studio normally(not under administrator account) and the application was working fine". That's not possible if your project uses IIS. So my suggestion is to find someone analyze your machine directly. If you can afford, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Answer (score 8):

Browse to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv and then double-click the “config” directory to get this warning dialog:

[image]

Click on the Continue button.

Do the same for the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\export directory and also the other directories in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.

Now you will be able to open the Visual Studio Web Application Project without a problem.

Comment: This one should mark as answer, worked for me, save me a day

Answer (score -2):

Just run Visual Studio as an Administrator and the problem will be solved.

from the Start menu or when Visual Studio is open on the taskbar, right-click the VS icon.
in the context menu, right-click the visual studio icon again.
left click on properties.
advanced choice.
choose Run as administrator.

Comment: Running the whole IDE as administrator is a very bad idea. You have no idea what kind of security implications that might have.

Comment: Some parts of VS don't work if you don't have admin rights. How about suggesting what the fix is also?